# How do i go about a login page in share Point Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, forms-authentication, user, custom-login-page

I have been working on share Point Online for more than a month now and i am quite used to it. I have this requirement to develop a custom login page with 
3 users :-
1.members 
2.admin
3. visitors 
With different rights to them.

For basics i just want to develop a login page for the site but i am not a central admin and i do not have access to database.
So how do i go about this any idea?
Thank You

Comment: nobody that uses sharepoint online has access to the database except microsoft... you do not need this page since when permissions are assigned everyone logs in and sees what they are permitted to see.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not supported to create a custom Sign In page for SharePoint Online (Office 365).

But we can add custom branding to Sign In page.

How to add custom branding to Office 365 Sign In page:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-your-company-branding-to-Office-365-Sign-In-page-a1229cdb-ce19-4da5-90c7-2b9b146aef0a

https://threewill.com/how-to-brand-your-office-365-login-page/

Comment: Honestly i don't have access to the Central Admin. Is there any other way to do this rather than using  azure directory signing in  ?